# Is it possible to call T-SQL function in Entity Framework and LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, t-sql

I tried this one:

```
GetProvinceCodeByLatLong(a.Latitude, a.Longitude)
```

And I declared the function like this:

```
[DbFunction("Core.Models", "fn_GetProvinceCodeByLatLong")]
public static string GetProvinceCodeByLatLong(double latitude, double longitude)
{
    throw new NotSupportedException("Direct calls are not supported.");
}
```

In edmx file I have this:

```
<Function Name="fn_GetProvinceCodeByLatLong" ReturnType="varchar" Aggregate="false" BuiltIn="false" NiladicFunction="false" IsComposable="true" ParameterTypeSemantics="AllowImplicitConversion" Schema="dbo">
  <Parameter Name="latitude" Type="float" Mode="In" />
  <Parameter Name="longitude" Type="float" Mode="In" />
</Function>
```

But Entity Framework throws the exception that the query cannot be constructed.

This error I receive:

> The specified method 'System.String GetProvinceCodeByLatLong(Double, Double)' on the type 'Infrastructure.CustomRepositories.AssetDataRepository' cannot be translated into a LINQ to Entities store expression

Comment: Have you tried http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.dataclasses.edmfunctionattribute(v=vs.110).aspx instead?

Comment: EdmFunction I think is obsolute function and instead of it we need to user DBFunction in newest EF

Answer (score -4, accepted):

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(targetConnexion))
    {
        Server server = new Server(new ServerConnection(conn));
        server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(File.ReadAllText(createDbScript));
    }
```

where createDbScript is just a file name. You can put anything

PS : It is within EF connexion btw

Comment: Sorry this is not for this question